# How to bound away integral over complex rectangle?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am integrating the following integral

> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos t}{e^t+e^{-t}}dt$$

by computing residues inside the rectangle with vertices $-R,R,-R+\pi i,R+\pi i$. On the left and right side of the rectangles, $\cos z$ is bounded, while $e^z+e^{-z}$ gets large, so the integral goes to zero. But what about the top side near the imaginary axis? How can we bound $\frac{\cos t}{e^t+e^{-t}}$ from above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note you can change the integral to

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{it}}{e^t+e^{-t}}dt$$

because $\frac{i\sin(t)}{e^t+e^{-t}}$ is odd.

Then if you proceed the same way you suggested, integrating along the top edge of the rectangle comes down to integrating

$$\frac{e^{i(t+i\pi)}}{e^{t+i\pi}+e^{-t-i\pi}}= (-e^{\pi}) \frac{e^{it}}{e^{t}+e^{-t}}$$

which is just a multiple of the bottom edge. That means when you add the four integrals you get the two side edges plus $(1+e^\pi)$ times the bottom edge. Note the change in sign because the top integral will be in the opposite direction of the bottom one. Then your final answer will be $(1+e^\pi)^{-1}$ times whatever the residue calculation is.